# Hiding NERDTree in VIM

Tags: vim

Does anyone have any clue on how I can toggle the TREE on and off ?

I went throught the help section of NERDTree plugin and don't see an option there ?

If anyone out there has discovered how to do this.. kindly share

Comment: Please read the [NerdTree FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree#faq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `:NERDTreeToggle` cmd does it.

personally I have

```
"toggle nerdtree
nnoremap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
```

in my vimrc. it allows me to press `<F2>` to show/hide nerdtree